# Grid columns shows 1px if all is set to Auto

Tags: wpf, grid

Why the Column 1 and 3 shows 1px if is empty?

```
<Grid>
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="Red"/>
            <Border Grid.Column="1" Background="Blue">
                <TextBlock Text="123"/>
             </Border>
            <Border Grid.Column="2" Background="Azure"/>
      </Grid>
```

Is bug or something that i don't understand?
Is possible to make Auto and Hide the 1px.

Edit: Need UseLayoutRounding="True". I have on Window.

Comment: They are empty with the exception of the border, so they auto size to that unless I am missing something

Comment: Given the markup you have posted, the first and last column should be invisible. Did you try this in a new project?

Comment: Rob Goodwin if i set Width 0 to border is the same 1px. Yes @mm8, is the same. Strange behavior.

Comment: @And-RoMarian: I can't reproduce it. Could you please include an image?

Comment: @mm8 found this. Try to add to Window: UseLayoutRounding="True"

Comment: @And-RoMarian: Good catch. So set this property to false or set the `Visibility` property of the `Border` elements to `Collapsed`.

Comment: @mm8 not working. is still there. but the color is transparent. I try with Width="0" too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193834/discussion-between-and-ro-marian-and-mm8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add and extra: `<ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>` and works fine.